# myssql table wrong date is getting inserted

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am updating one og the tables and that table requires an end date.

```
LocalDate new_end_date = LocalDate.parse(endDate);
```

Here endDate is a string so I am converting it to a `LocalDate`.This is what I am getting `new_end_date :2023-08-10` when I am printing this. but in the update query

```
update config_db.user_config_data set end_date='2023-08-09',cnf_version=45 where uid='user12' and key_id='key12';
```

Now in update query it gets changed from 10 to 09 how can I fix this.Please someone solve my issue or atleast give me a path to how i can I solve this.

Comment: From your question i understand that your end_date is `2023-08-10` and when you run a update query to set it to `2023-08-09` it gets updated to `09`,is that what you are asking?

Comment: @AjajAli Yes that's exactly what is happeing right now.

Comment: Please show the exact value of `endDate` when you execute your `LocalDate new_end_date = LocalDate.parse(endDate);
`

Comment: @Asgar 2023-08-10 this is exactly what I am getting.

Comment: Please mention the data type of `end_date` in your entity class

Comment: It's a string like this . String end_date = "2023-08-10".

Comment: If it is  String in your entity class, why do you need to parse it into 'LocalDate'?

Comment: @Asgar Thanks mate. I have no idea why I was doing that my bad. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

it might give error when parsing the date from the string, if database table is in different time zone you can try below code.

```
ZonedDateTime new_end_date  = ZonedDateTime.parse(endDate);
```

Comment: Can you explain more? How updating a date explicitly from code might result in changing date in a database in a different time zone?